# Trying to draw this figure using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to draw this figure:

### Figure

[image]

---

I used TikZiT, but I could have used TikZ directly or Pgfplots, because I don't know squat about any of them. So far I've got this:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
    \node [style=Blue] (3) at (0, 9) {VistaEstacioEsqui};
    \node [style=Blue] (5) at (-10, 7) {IniciadorEstacioEsqui};
    \node [style=Blue] (6) at (0, 3) {EstacioEsqui};
    \node [style=Blue] (8) at (-10, 2) {LlistaRemuntadors};
    \node [style=Blue] (9) at (7, -6) {Pista};
    \node [style=Blue] (10) at (0, 0) {ArrayList};
    \node [style=Blue] (11) at (-10, -2) {Remuntador};
    \node [style=Blue] (12) at (-4, -4) {Teleferic};
    \node [style=Blue] (13) at (-7.25, -7) {Teleesqui};
    \node [style=Blue] (14) at (-12, -7) {Telecadira};
    \node [style=Blue] (15) at (-16.5, -5) {Telecabina};
    \node [style=Blue] (16) at (-19, -2) {CintaTransportadora};
    \node [style=new style 0] (17) at (-10, 11) {Menu};
    \node [style=redish] (19) at (8, 4) {Meteo};
    \node [style=Blue] (20) at (10, 0) {LlistaPistes};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
    \draw [style=new edge style 0] (3) to (6);
    \draw [style=new edge style 0] (5) to (3);
    \draw [style=new edge style 0] (3) to (17);
    \draw [style=new edge style 0] (6) to (19);
    \draw [style=new edge style 0] (6) to (8);
    \draw [style=new edge style 0] (8) to (10);
    \draw [style=new edge style 0] (8) to (11);
    \draw [style=new edge style 1] (11) to (16);
    \draw [style=new edge style 1] (11) to (15);
    \draw [style=new edge style 1] (11) to (14);
    \draw [style=new edge style 1] (11) to (13);
    \draw [style=new edge style 1] (11) to (12);
    \draw [style=new edge style 0] (6) to (20);
    \draw [style=new edge style 0] (20) to (10);
    \draw [style=new edge style 0] (20) to (9);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Could anyone help me improve it? Mine it's rather dull and doesn't have these special arrows ("implementa"). As many of you can imagine, it's a diagram of a OOP Java program. The special arrow point from the subclass to its superclass.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have to write those styles for each and every node or edge. You would benefit from writing your styles before your picture, with `tikzset{mynode/.style={fill=cyan,minimum width=2cm,...}}` and then just use into your tikzpicture like this: `\node[mynode] (1) at (0,0) {node content};`. Same thing for the edges. For the arrows, see `arrows.meta` library.

Comment: Hey Seb, it's how TikZiT works: I didn't write it, I just structured the diagram. In fact, rawpasting this code on a LaTeX document results in a compilation error.

Comment: I'm sure of it. This comment was meant to inform OP, actually ;)